# Why Adobe is recommending McAfee security scan during flash player installation?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, software

Why is Adobe recommending a McAfee security scan during the installation of flash player?

Comment: Strange. Never got that prompt while installing Flash.

Comment: Flash Player? What is that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's an affiliate thing. Adobe get paid to promote McAfee's anti-malware software. You have nothing to worry about in terms of security, it's just a marketing trick to get you to buy an AV.

Comment: oh, but I **do** worry when it gets down to this, when an AV scans your system, it also creates reports that will be uploaded to their servers, that information **can** contain sensitive information related to me and/or my client(s).

Comment: Computer - that is a totally separate issue, and while it **may** be true, the vast majority of the time it isn't

Comment: Moichendizing! Moichendizing! McAfee the Antivirus. McAfee the breakfast cereal.

Comment: Only an issue if you're running one of the competitor's AV packages and it turns out to be one that's incompatible with McAfee's particular iteration. It's been known to get in a knife fight with Kaspersky, leaving bystanders variously traumatized.

Comment: @ScottPack, "breakfast cereal"? What does your comment mean?

Comment: @Pacerier It's a reference to [a scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNZove4OTtI) from Spaceballs.

Comment: I deeply NOT agree with that : 'just a marketing trick'. When you say "have nothing to worry about in terms of security", this sounds like you did not figure out yet why adobe published a weekly update for flash since internet updates are available. Google for "Steve Jobs’ thoughts on Flash"

Comment: @MilchePatern You're talking about the general security of Flash, which is a totally different matter to this specific affiliate marketing campaign. Also, Steve Jobs was a businessman and marketing director, not an engineer or coder - his thoughts on the security of Flash are irrelevant to this particular topic. Even if we were to entertain his opinions, they mostly rely upon the complaint that Flash is proprietary, which again has little bearing on the actual security of the product.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe is installing a highly limited version of McAfee antivirus on your system and then doing a limited scan to possibly find malware (as expected with limited software). Adobe also pushes the Bing toolbar, the Google toolbar and the Google Chrome Browser at you among other offerings they've included. Funny thing is their installer routine is not intelligent enough to check for prior installations before recommending any of this software.

While there are good intentions in recommending this software, (McAfee for people with no antivirus at all **might** be a good thing, the Chrome Browser **might** be more secure than Internet Explorer) it's mostly done as an affiliate kickback program to provide a revenue stream for Adobe's "free" Flash plugins and Acrobat Reader.

It's not totally harmless as the McAfee scanner has been incompatible with already installed competitor's antivirus packages, sometimes knocking them out of action or preventing their virus signature updates from working. Also, reinstalling Chrome on a system that already has it installed can mess the Chrome Browser install up to the point I've had to reinstall Chrome.

When you manually trigger Adobe Flash, Adobe Reader and Oracle Java updates, you can tell the upgrade to not include these affiliate packages. They also can be removed through Windows add/remove programs routines if you have problems with them. As they are legitimate software annoyingly installed, they follow the rules for uninstall.

Comment: Chrome Browser **is**  more secure than Internet Explorer.

Comment: When that is offered by your Adobe Flash upgrade screen instead of McAfee... And as of late in 2015, Chrome is more secure than Internet Explorer. Back in 2012, Chrome was having some issues as well. Disclosure: Chrome is my major goto of choice for iffy websites, Firefox for dev features I like that are sometimes more user friendly than Chrome and IE as webdev compatibility tester and very little else.

Comment: @Firefox, What's wrong with using Chrome for dev? Why use Firefox which seems abit "clunky"?

Comment: Nothing at all, just personal preferences, Chrome and Firefox are often open side by side anyway during dev along with the IDE and a Virtualbox VM running the Linux server. Joy of running an i7 with plenty of memory and screen realestate.

Comment: How much would that cost?

Answer (score 4):

I just updated Adobe's Flash Player and it didn't even offer me the option **NOT** to install the McAfee junk. Luckily I have a program called "**WinPatrol**" installed, which alerts me to anything attempting to install itself in my **Start-Ups** and gives me the option to say **NO**. Then I can simply uninstall the junk.

Answer (score 3):

As Polynomial says, there is that affiliation - many companies promote other installs when you update or install a package. It is pretty common business.

That said, it is **always** a good idea to scan any new software that you install. If you already have a good A/V or antimalware solution, stick with that, otherwise I would recommend getting one.